# Gif starts a second time if Other Gif loads! I don`t no why?

Tags: javascript, php

I've some buttons/img, which displays the status of the items in the database. On hovering should the src changed to a gif, which ends after the animated part. On leaving should the other gif come. If I entered and leaved the first button and I do the same with another button, on leaving the second time all of the two gifs loads new. The same happens with more than 2 times also.

Here a example:
[image]

```js
function lightimgchange (ID, Val) {
        var imgID = 'light' + ID;
        var elem = document.getElementById(imgID);
        if (Val == 1) {
            elem.src = "img/light_on_off.gif";
        }
        else {
            elem.src = "img/light_off_on.gif";
        }
}
```

```html
while ($reihe = mysql_fetch_array($light_db)) {
        if ($reihe['Status'] == 'Y') {
        echo "<img src='img/light_on.png' alt='On' id='light".$reihe['ID']."' height='75px' width='75px' onmouseenter='lightimgchange(".$reihe['ID'].", 1)' onmouseleave='lightimgchange(".$reihe['ID'].", 0)' style='border-radius:20%;'>";
        }
        else {
        echo "<img src='img/light_off.png' alt='Off' id='light".$reihe['ID']."' height='75px' width='75px' onmouseenter='lightimgchange(".$reihe['ID'].", 0)' onmouseleave='lightimgchange(".$reihe['ID'].", 1)' style='border-radius:20%;'>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve solved it with a trick. After ending, I change the gif to a png.

Here`s the js solution:

```
function lightimgchange (ID, Val) {
    var imgID = 'light' + ID;
    var elem = document.getElementById(imgID);
    if (Val == 1) {
        elem.src = "img/light_on_off.gif";
        setTimeout(function(){
            elem.src = "img/light_off.png";
        }, 450);
    }
    else {
        elem.src = "img/light_off_on.gif";
        setTimeout(function(){
            elem.src = "img/light_on.png";
        }, 450);
    }
}
```